# Wants to insert data from one database to another in one request

Tags: php, mysql, curl

In my first application let say **"sms"** a php file **"sms_transfer.php"** fetch some data from **"SMS database"** and sends curl request to another application let say **"phone"** php file **phone_get.php**,
which receive that data and on the based of that data mapped some ids from **"phone Database"**.

Now i want to return that mapped data and ids to **"sms Application"** and stored them in one of **"SMS database"** application Table.what is the right approach to do this task , how it could be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can send data over with json_encode and json_decode.. Thats how I usually do it.